# Hazelcast filtering topic messages through MessageListener with a predicate

Tags: java, hazelcast

When I register a MessageListener on an ITopic, can I specify a Predicate somewhere?  I see some support for Predicates in the EventService SPI, but it doesn't look like it's exposed publicly in ITopic like the corresponding methods in IMap are.  Is there a safe way around this with the latest Hazelcast version?

EventService has a method prototype "EventRegistration registerListener(String serviceName, String topic, EventFilter filter, Object listener)" so it appears like it's supported, in theory.

Bonus 1: Are the Predicates applied on the node that generates the events, for efficiency?  Bonus 2: If a node with registered listeners dies, will Hazelcast automatically evict the listener registrations so the generating nodes no longer send messages to downed nodes via their registrations?

Comment: When you say "specify a Predicate somewhere", do you mean specifying a predicate in MessageListener impl? Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve here with Predicate in the context of ITopic? As for your bonus questions, 1. Predicates are applied on all nodes in the cluster 2. An event is created only if you registered an event listener. If no listener is registered, then no event is created.

Comment: I'd like to specify a predicate when I add a topic listener, as if the ITopic class had "String addMessageListener(MessageListener<E> listener, Predicate<E> predicate)". But there's no method there that accepts a Predicate. I'd also like the predicates to be checked (early) by the node /generating/ the event so a node with an actual listener doesn't have to filter it after it's been sent over the wire.  This assumes the predicates would be replicated along with the listener registration info.

Comment: Do you mean a Predicate for Topic? If so then thats not possible. If not then it is still not clear as what is the objective of mixing the two data structures (IMap and Topic) here. I am not saying you can not use the 2 data structures together, I am just not able to understand the problem case here properly.

Comment: Yeah I guess a predicate filter doesn't make any sense as the Predicate class is tied to the key/value pattern of the IMap. It looks like I'll need to get Hazelcast's EventService myself and implement EventFilter instead.  I just thought there might be a more publicly-accessible method of filtering topic events than going through the SPI.